# ntoskrnl.exe+7211eb 0x00000124 BSOD

Tags: windows-10, bsod, dropbox

Windows 10 64bit. I've been having consistent crashes when running intensive applications. I have tried running memtest with no results and updating drivers.

Minidump
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xz1m0v0l3ljapcu/090517-48859-01.dmp?dl=0

CPU-Z report
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b6u1wqfdo4yfvyo/DESKTOP-K1EQJ94.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

[Bugcheck 0x124 means Fatal Hardware issue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x124---whea-uncorrectable-error)

> The WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR bug check has a value of 0x00000124. This
>   bug check indicates that a fatal hardware error has occurred.

Analyzing the dump with Windbg.exe shows that you get `BUSLG_GENERIC_ERR_*_TIMEOUT_ERR` error.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: ffff890e96f6c038, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 0000000000000000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000000000000, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.15063.540 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 0

BUGCHECK_P2: ffff890e96f6c038

BUGCHECK_P3: 0

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_AuthenticAMD

CPU_COUNT: 6

CPU_MHZ: dbc

CPU_VENDOR:  AuthenticAMD

CPU_FAMILY: 15

CPU_MODEL: 2

CPU_STEPPING: 0

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!WheapCreateLiveTriageDump
01 nt!WheapCreateTriageDumpFromPreviousSession
02 nt!WheapProcessWorkQueueItem
03 nt!WheapWorkQueueWorkerRoutine
04 nt!ExpWorkerThread
05 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup
06 nt!KiStartSystemThread


MODULE_NAME: AuthenticAMD

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x124_AuthenticAMD_PROCESSOR_BUS_PRV
```

You use the F2 BIOS for your GA-78LMT-USB3:

```
DMI BIOS        
    vendor          Award Software International Inc.
    version         F2
    date            11/25/2014
    ROM size        4096 KB

DMI System Information      
    manufacturer        Gigabyte Technology Co. Ltd.
    product         GA-78LMT-USB3
```

so update the BIOS and look if this improves stability.

Comment: F2 is the newest version available for this motherboard sadly.

Comment: do you have a different CPU to test (from a friend other family members)?